# QR Code library for Go

Tags: go, qr-code

Is there a library to generate QR Codes with the Go programming language? I'm looking for something in pure Go that generates image files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Russ has done some funny things with QR codes and his tool
is available here:
http://code.google.com/p/rsc/source/browse/qr